# Identityserver id_token in cookie makes cookie size large

Tags: cookies, token, identityserver3

I have been putting id_token in authorization cookie since you need this token while doing single sign out.

```
notification.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = 
    notification.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token").Value;
```

However, it makes the cookie size larger. So, we were thinking if this is the only time, we need it, it would perhaps be not a bad idea to store it in a database for the user. This way, we could retrieve it before doing the sign out and send it to the ids and will also keep the authorization cookie size smaller. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to store the id_token anywhere you see fit. It's only needed for signout.